# Images not served over symlinks

Tags: multistore, image, product-images, media, not-found

I managed to create multiple store by using the subdirectory + symlinking method. Everything works fine except that images are not found! I made sure that I created a symlink for the media folder, and tried to manually browse to file specified as not found. The files are there, its just that my website doesn't see/find them.
I am quite sure that this has something to do with the symlinking as css, js and other folders are served correctly.

**UPDATE**

In my system.log file it gives me this error for every image that is being loaded:

```
2015-07-21T08:04:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open '/www/reservo/media/catalog/product/cache/7/small_image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/J/O/JOK90X9016_2.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory  in /www/reservo/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 166
```

Comment: More details on your directory structure would help. `var/logs/exceptions.log may offer more insight.

Comment: @B00MER updated

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the webserver/php process user/group can access the file? permissions may be the issue.